# How to add selenium dlls to test studio?

Tags: telerik

Can anyone tell me how to add selenium dlls to test studio and write selenium code in [Telerik Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/teststudio).

When i am trying to add selenium dlls to Test Studio using "Settings" -> Script - Add Reference it is not taking the selenium dll files.

[image]

Comment: As Test studio is a proprietary application I would also ask on their forums and email their support. http://www.telerik.com/support/teststudio Just to be sure what you are trying todo is really valid :) Goodluck in finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using this method, because:

- This is tool-dependent;
- You cannot replicate this procedure with one-click - both if you have a new computer or if you want to distribute the project in a team.
- You won't have control (and probably have any idea) on which version of your dependencies you are using.

You should consider using a [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager). Assuming you are using C#, an option is the [NuGet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/), which is developed by Microsoft. It has [many packages related to Selenium](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=selenium). You can see how to specify your configuration file [here](https://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=.nuspec%20v1.2%20Format).

Comment: I know i can do it through NuGet in Visual Studio. I don't want that. I want to import selenium packages in TestStudio. Let me know if you can import selenium dependencies into test studio. Forget about distribution and version of my dependencies. I simply want to import selenium dependencies into test studio. Let me know whether we can be able to do it by any means

Comment: Have you tried using NuGet in this project? You should be able use the dependencies independently of the IDE you are using.